# Regex for wrong quoted CSV-File

Tags: php, regex, csv, preg-match

I have problem with some corrupt csv-File. I get it like that:

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6
123,"some text",""column3 text"",""still column3 text"",4,234,""
123,"some text",""column3 text"",4,234,""
```

In table it should look like that:

```
column1 | column2   | column3                            | column4 | column5 | column6
123     | some text | "column3 text, still column3 text" | 4       | 234     | 
123     | some text | "column3 text"                     | 4       | 234     |
```

I am reading the file with php and tried to use it with str_getcsv into array. But because of this broken quotes it won't work and always have more columns than titles.

At all I don't need value of column 3 so I tried to do some regex to make three groups and do preg_replace then. But I don't get a regex that works for both lines.

With this regex I get just first line: https://regex101.com/r/OjTAAC/1

and with this I get just second line: https://regex101.com/r/I2xqPs/1

Anybody has some help how to get a regex that works for both situations?

Comment: There must be some other way, [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/ngiijv/1) seems too cumbersome.

Comment: the empty "" at the end will make problems

Comment: you could split lines and do a case by case regex dependind on the number of commas

Comment: I think the file is just too corrupt to make sense of. I mean besides the fact that you say "still column3" what's the rule that says that it's still column 3?

Comment: There is also an excel export and column 3 value is ' "column3 text, still column3 text" '. But in CSV-Export it looks like ' ""column3 text"",""still column3 text"" '. I know it is totally broken. But I can not wait until it will be fixed.

Comment: I have tried [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/OjTAAC/4). But there is a bit of a problem. `(?<=")[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+(?<!")|""[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+""|\w+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be simpler solution, I would backup or have a copy of the file though and you may have to do it different it it's large.

Lets try something different

```
//$str = '123,"some text",""column3 text"",""still column3 text"",4,234,""';
//$str = '123,"some text",""column3 text"",4,234,""'

while (($str = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {      
     $str = str_replace('"', '', $str);
    $line = explode(',',$str);

    //combine line item 2,3
    if(count($line) == 7 ){
        $line[2] .= ', '.$line[3];
        //remove item 3
        unset($line[3]);
        $line = array_values($line);
    } 
    print_r( $line );
}
```

As long as the lines are consistent with what you show it should work.

```
$array =[
    '123,"some text",""column3 text"",""still column3 text"",4,234,""',
    '123,"some text",""column3 text"",4,234,""'
];

foreach($array as $str){
    $str = str_replace('"', '', $str);
    $line = explode(',',$str);

    //combine line item 2,3
    if(count($line) == 7 ){
        $line[2] .= ', '.$line[3];
        //remove item 3
        unset($line[3]);
        $line = array_values($line);
    } 
    print_r( $line );
}
```

Outputs

```
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => some text
    [2] => column3 text, still column3 text
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 234
    [5] =>
)
Array
(
    [0] => 123
    [1] => some text
    [2] => column3 text
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 234
    [5] =>
)
```

You can test it here.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f39eb94ccef045213a30385cc7daa326ce3aa25d

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, But my problem is not the "" at the end of line. It is the Column3 value which is totally broken in CSV-File.

Comment: As I said In my answer the `""` at the end of the line is perfectly valid.  What i put will work as long as there are no valid double quotes `""`, the one at the end being an example of a valid double quote.

Comment: Yeah, that would be a working solution. The idea to replace all "" I did not have yet. My workaround looks like that at the moment http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8e6c63130111cda0018aaf545fd021397fe4e80c

Comment: Yea the `"` are just mostly, junk in this case.